# Click a class to show a li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a menu system the toggles/ shows (would be nice to fade or toggle) the contents of an element. So the user does not have to change page. normally would use ajax (.load) but dont want other files holding the text (due to cms).

Cant seem to get it to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/feto4ymt/7/

**UPDATE**

Still breaks primary menu system, but this secondary menu system nested in it does not break now:
https://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/35/

Before with to slide menu systems one nested in another:
https://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/34/

Before (each menu system in solo operation mode where they both work fine)
Main:  http://jsfiddle.net/3to0neLm/1
Nested in the Main Li: http://jsfiddle.net/feto4ymt/1

**Script**

```
$(".tab_item2").click(function() {
$(".tab_item2").removeClass(".tab_item_color2");
$(this).addClass(".tab_item_color2");
$(".tabitem2").show(".slide_content2");
});
```

Comment: Do I get you right, that you want to display 2222222.. on click of "the science", 333333... on click of "order" etc.?

Comment: yes so each menu item on left, will display the li in that order.

Comment: I was trying to slide it but it will go inside another system that does slide but breaks down:  i just made 3 fiddel so you can see what i am trying to do
first here is a slide li element once span is clicked jsfiddle.net/3to0neLm/1
second slide lie element once span is clicked: jsfiddle.net/feto4ymt/1
They both work fine. Now put second slide into one of the li's in the first slide (now it breaks down) : jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/34

Comment: so trying to make it simpler so when i put it into the li of another system it wont break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.show` use `.fadeTo` this will add fading animation to guest271314 answer:

```js
 $(".tab_item2").click(function() {
   $(".tab_item2").removeClass("tab_item_color2");
   $(this).addClass("tab_item_color2");
   $(".tabslider2 li").hide().eq($(this).index(".tab_item2")).fadeTo("slow", 1, function() {
     // Animation complete.
   });
 });
```

```css
.tabbed_content {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.tabs {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
.tabs .moving_bg {
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url(/images/arrow_down_blue.png);
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  z-index: 7;
  left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.tab_item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  color: #bbb;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 8;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-SemiBold';
  font-size: 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.tab_item:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
}
.tab_item_color {
  color: #fff;
}
.slide_content {
  width: 1100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 26px 10px 0 5px;
}
.tabslider {
  width: 6000px;
  color: #222;
  background: #fff;
}
.tabslider ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 1100px;
}
.tabslider li
/*media adjust */

{
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 1090px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
.tabslider ul a {
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabslider ul a:hover {
  color: #222;
}
.tabslider ul li {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}
.tabbed_content2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.tabs2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
}
.tabs2 .moving_bg2 {
  background-color: ;
  background-image: url(/images/arrow_down_blue.png);
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 7;
  left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.tab_item2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  color: #bbb;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 8;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-SemiBold';
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.tab_item2:hover {
  color: #333;
}
.tab_item_color2 {
  color: #333;
}
.slide_content2 {
  width: 910px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 26px 10px 0 5px;
  float: left;
}
.tabslider2 {
  width: 6000px;
  color: #222;
}
.tabslider2 ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 910px;
}
.tabslider2 li
/*media adjust */

{
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 900px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
.tabslider2 ul a {
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabslider2 ul a:hover {
  color: #222;
}
.tabslider2 ul li {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}
.bodymainMax {
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  overflow: visible;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.bodymainMaxS {
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  overflow: visible;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.bblock1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  clear: both;
}
.bblock3body {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  clear: both;
}
.bblock1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  clear: both;
}
.bblock2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #217DD1;
  clear: both;
  min-height: 3px;
}
.bblock3 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  clear: both;
}
.container {
  width: 1130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bblock1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bodymainMaxS">
      <div class='tabbed_content2'>
        <div class='tabs2'>
          <div class='moving_bg2'>&nbsp;</div>
          <span class='tab_item2 tab_item_color2'>OVERVIEW</span>
          <span class='tab_item2'>THE SCIENCE</span>
          <span class='tab_item2'>ORDER</span>
          <span class='tab_item2'>REPLACEMENT FILTERS</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='slide_content2'>
        <ul class='tabslider2'>
          <li>11111111111111111111111111111111111111</li>
          <li>2222222222222222222222222222222222222c</li>
          <li>333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</li>
          <li>44444444444444444444444444444444444444</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: thought i would make the second menu in the primary more basic to stop it from breaking but even with this code it gets errors

Comment: good thing is only the primary slider is now broken vs before they both go crazy

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.eq()`, `.index()`, `.hide()`

```
$(".tab_item2").click(function() {
  $(".tab_item2").removeClass("tab_item_color2");
  $(this).addClass("tab_item_color2");
  // hide all `.tabslider2 li` elements,
  // select, show `.tabslider2 li` element at current `.tab_item2` index
  $(".tabslider2 li").hide().eq($(this).index(".tab_item2")).show();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/feto4ymt/14/

Comment: @david Approach using `.fadeOut()`, `.fadeIn()` https://jsfiddle.net/feto4ymt/40/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/35 - hi thanks still breaks the primary slider that it is nested in. is it because of the eq in the primary then targeting the second menu system? ( when you click the top links you will see that the last two are blank instead of displaying some text).

Comment: @david _"still breaks th eprimary slider that it is nested in"_ Not sure what you mean by "breaks"? _"when you click the top links you will see that the last two are blank instead of displaying some text"_ Is requirement to not hide text, but only change `color` or `class` of element?

Comment: should operate like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3to0neLm/1 , but when i place the second menu system, the one you just fixed it breaks the primary one. the color class of element is just for the menu hover, so after a hover item is clicked the class keeps it shaded like the hover state. this works fine. just didnt include the css for it.

Comment: @david The original Question did not include `html` or `javascript` described at http://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/35 ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Instead of "updating" original Question with an entirely new Question, perhaps ask another Question relevant to the `html`, `javascript` at http://jsfiddle.net/ph3ng2fo/35 ?

Comment: OK will open a new question

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your issue.

```
$(".tab_item2").click(function() {
  $(".tab_item2").removeClass("tab_item_color2");
  $(this).addClass("tab_item_color2");
  $(".tabslider2 li").hide();
  $(".tabslider2 li:eq("+ ($(this).index() - 1) +")" ).show();
});
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/feto4ymt/11/

update https://jsfiddle.net/feto4ymt/21/

Answer (score 0):

```
                    <div class='tabs2'>
                    <div class='moving_bg2'>&nbsp;</div>
                    <span class='tab_item2 tab_item_color2' id="tab2_1">OVERVIEW</span>
                    <span class='tab_item2' id="tab2_2">THE SCIENCE</span>
                    <span class='tab_item2' id="tab2_3">ORDER</span>
                    <span class='tab_item2' id="tab2_4">REPLACEMENT FILTERS</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='slide_content2'>                        
                <ul class='tabslider2'>
                    <li class="tab2_1">11111111111111111111111111111111111111</li>
                    <li class="tab2_2">2222222222222222222222222222222222222c</li>
                    <li class="tab2_3">333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333</li>
                    <li class="tab2_4">44444444444444444444444444444444444444</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <script>
                $(".tab_item2").click(function() {
                    var custom_class = $(this).attr('id');
                $('.tabslider2 li').hide(); 
                $('.tabslider2 li.'+custom_class).show();

                $(".tab_item2").removeClass("tab_item_color2");
                $(this).addClass("tab_item_color2");
               //$(".tabitem2").show("slide_content2");
                });
            </script>
```